# Command Line `defaultLogLevel=debug` does not not output debug messages

Tags: java, maven, slf4j

Good morning, I have been googling solutions for two days trying to understand how to get my `log.debug("...")` messages to output.  My research into the problem indicates that I should only have to pass in an argument via command line when launching my app.  That seems not to be the case.

I am using IntelliJ. I am using Maven.

#### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--- some content removed for brevity -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

#### App.java

```
import org.slf4j.*;

public class App {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        log.info("Info");
        log.debug("Debug");
        log.warn("Warn");
        log.error("Error");
    }
}
```

#### The Output

```
java -Dorg.sl4fj.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=DEBUG -cp C:\testapp\target\classes;C:\Users\613296\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.5\slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar;C:\Users\613296\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-simple\1.7.5\slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar App 
[main] INFO App - Info
[main] WARN App - Warn
[main] ERROR App - Error

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The debug message never gets output!  I've confirmed all the jar files in my classpath are present.  The option `-Dorg.sl4fj.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=DEBUG` is what I thought would make this work (according to **a lot** of reading I've done).  So, I must be missing something vital.  Please help me understand what I need to do to achieve my goal!

Answer (score 0):

Move it *before* `App` in the command line so the JVM sees it.

All arguments after the class to invoke are passed in the `args` parameter.  (Try printing it out)

Comment: I moved it and reran the command, but it did not change the output.

Comment: Show new command line

Comment: `java -Dorg.sl4fj.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=DEBUG -cp C:\testapp\target\classes;C:\Users\613296\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.5\slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar;C:\Users\613296\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-simple\1.7.5\slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar App` -- I also updated my original question to show the new command line.